# How to write a one character file using Python with mime type `text/plain`?

Tags: python, file, mime-types

How can I write a one character file in Python 3.8 that has the `text/plain` mime type?

Using Python, if I write one character to a file, the mime type of the file is `application/octet-stream`.

```
with open('file_from_python', 'w') as f: f.write('x')
```

(Note: Writing more than one character using the Python code above results in the `text/plain` mime type; the issue only occurs when you write less than two characters to a file).

Check the mime type of the python generated file using the following Linux command line:

```
file --mime-type file_from_python 
file_from_python: application/octet-stream
```

Using the Linux terminal, if I write one character to a file, the mime type of the file is `text/plain`.

```
echo "x" > file_from_bash
```

Check the mime type of the Linux terminal generated file using the following Linux command line:

```
file --mime-type file_from_bash
file_from_bash: text/plain
```

Comment: What you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to be sure that the file is saved using the mime type `text/plain` even when there are zero characters or only one character in the file. (This is for a GUI application where the user can save an empty file, or save a file with only one character. My application checks the file's mime type before re-opening a file for editing by the user. Currently the new file will not open, because its mime type is incorrect after saving. Files created with two or more characters do not have this problem).

Comment: A "proper" `text/plain` file has a newline at the end of each line.  Compare the lengths of your Python and bash files, they'll be 1 and 2 respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [file](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=file) command is just applying heuristics to give a pretty good guess at the file type. It can't guess very well for a 1 byte file, so it gives up.

This bit of Python will produce a file identical to your bash command:

```
with open('file_from_python_text', 'w') as f: f.write('x\n')
```

Echo adds a newline.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how your app checks mime type but you should be aware that mime type is not really associated with file content. It's derrived from it (because that's the only sane way) but there's nothing preventing you say that i. e. JPG file is `text/plain` and plain text file is `application/octet-stream` or even `image/jpeg`. In other words you can easily tell what mime type it is based on your own rules if needed. Also `file` opinion is not definitive nor authoritative even if it's often right.